# Who trigger the initialization of primitive types?

Tags: java, initialization, primitive

I was wondering who/what trigger the initialization of the primitive types in Java for example:

```
public class A {
    int primitive;
    String nonPrimitive;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A newObject = new A();
    }
}
```

So when we create the new instance of `A`, the default constructor of `A` class is called. String extends Object, so then the constructor of Object is called and `nonPrimitive` var has been created and have **null** value.

But what is the situation with **primitive** variable? If it is initialized directly by the VM with default value 0 and if the creation of the new `newObject` triggered it? Or it is created before creating the  `newObject`?

Answer (score 5):

When the object is created, its fields are created.

```
new A();
```

The fields are initialized, each with its default value - according to what's stated in the [JLS **4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For all reference types ([§4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)), the default value is **null**.

That's why String is initialized with `null`. See the full table to see other values (yes, integer class variables are set to 0 by default).

See also [12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4), it explains in details what happens when class is initialized.